# Creating data partitions not working correctly (caret package)

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I am trying to make a machine learning model using a train and test set, using createDataPartition(). I am able to make a linear model for the training set, but I cannot seem to fit new data to the existing model, e.g. to two principal components of the data set.

This is an example from a course on machine learning, which gives an error.

```
library(kernlab); library(caret)
data(spam)

inTrain <- createDataPartition(y=spam$type, p =0.75, list = FALSE)
training <- spam[inTrain,]
testing <- spam[-inTrain,]

    #preprocess the training data by log transform for skewed 
    #variables, and then extract the first two principal components 

preProc <- preProcess(log10(training[,-58]+1), method = "pca", pcaComp 
= 2)
preProc$rotation

    #create a train-dataset based on the prediction of the two PC's 
    #from the training set

trainPC <- predict(preProc, log10(training[,-58]+1))

     #train the 'type' versus all other variables model using a GLM, 
     #but based on the trainPC dataset, containing the two principal 
     #components

modelFit <- train(training$type ~ . ,  method="glm", data = trainPC)

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , all.vars(Terms), drop = FALSE) : 
undefined columns selected
```

The expected result is that modelFit is trained for training$type but uses the newly created trainPC data set, which was predicted from the preprocessed data.

I think the problem is that the trainPC data only contains two PC's and cannot be referred to when training, if I am correct:

```
train(training$type ~ .
```

Thanks in advance!

Alexander

Comment: Seems kind of a reversal of the expected order to call `predict` before calling `train`. I suppose such an order could be proper if the caret package uses non-standard terminology, but if so then this is the first time I have encountered a question that demonstrates such. This question suffers from posting an error without any data or even a good description of such, and from not posting the error message in the context of the code where the error was reported. You should [edit] and add further details.

Comment: @42 the `predict` here refers to `preProcess`, not to model `train`; agree about the rest

Comment: Where *exactly* does the error pop up? During `train` or when trying to apply the model to test data, as you imply? If the latter, please post the relevant code

Comment: Updated the post. The error occurs when calculating modelFit.

Comment: I think I found the error: the modelFit works when I just use " type" instead of training$type.